# turbostat - TSC_MHz average MHz that the TSC ran during the entire interval

Tags: performance, cpu, utilities

When using 'turbostat' command, we can see 'TSC_MHz' field data.

What does 'TSC ran' here mean?

OS in idle state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more explicit way of phrasing this is “average frequency at which the TSC incremented over the entire interval”. The TSC counts CPU cycles: it increments every time the CPU clock ticks. This happens regardless of what the computer is doing. Frequency variations reflect the varying clock rate: typically, if the CPU is idle, it is slowed down, and if it’s busy, sped up. (“Constant” TSCs however tick at the CPU’s nominal frequency.)

The formula is (“TSC at end” - “TSC at start”) ÷ (“time at end” - “time at start”).

In `turbostat`, the frequency values shown are as follows:

- `Avg_MHz`: “useful” frequency, *i.e.* the number of cycles executed divided by the time elapsed
- `Bzy_MHz`: frequency at which the CPU ran when it had something to do, *i.e.* when it was in C0, not idle
- `TSC_MHz`: frequency at which the TSC ran, as explained above

Comment: at any time, CPU should work at a freq, what's the difference between working frequency, TSC freq, Bzy_MHz? There are more than 1 freq at the same time?

Comment: Yes, the CPU only works at a single frequency at any given time; `turbostat` measures different frequencies which describe different measurements, see my updated answer.